# Modelling approach for large data set with many small clusters and rare outcome

Tags: mixed-model, large-data, nested-data, genetics, rare-events

Hi, I am trying to find out whether a certain behavioral trait in birds is heritable and have ~ 10K 3-generation pedigrees of birds (N total birds ~ 200K). Not all pedigrees have 3 generations of data--for some birds, we were only able to trace 2 generations. The outcome is odds of the grandchildren birds have binary trait X given trait X data in ancestors at different coefficients of kinship. Among ancestors, there are multiple individuals at each coefficient of kinship--parents of the grandchildren birds are both first-degree relatives of the grandchildren birds, etc. Also, some grandchildren birds have the same parents.

I think there are at least 3 issues/things to handle in modelling the data--clustering of grandchildren birds by parents, clustering of ancestors at the same kinship coefficient for each grandchild bird, and rare outcome (~2% among all grandchildren birds). I've tried the frequentist's mixed effects model to handle the 2 levels of clustering, and of course the model threw up and data were mad. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated!